# Two database? One for user & content the other for structure?

Tags: database

For site builders like me who do not do much programing but theming of existing modules and functions. Since those items such as views, panels, user badges, rules, points e.g. are written into the database. It makes updating a lot harder.

Is it possible for Drupal to be able to store user data, and user created content, and messages on one database(say A) and everything else on database (B)?

THe idea behind this is that this way it will allow me to easily update site structure (views, panels) without affecting production data created from the users.

Is this possible and or doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, perhaps.

In practice, I think you're in for a world of pain.

Others frequently solve your problem by instead exporting configuration using [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features).

That is also the direction in which Drupal 8 is headed, with the [CMI Initiative](http://drupal8cmi.org/).

Comment: So with features it moves it them into a code file?

Comment: Features allows you to export configuration, such as a View, to code yes. This can then be tracked with a VCS such as git, and deployed to production in a safe and automated fashion.